# How to display HTML in jQuery autocomplete results in Rails

Tags: ruby, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-4

I am populating a set of results for jQuery UI autocomplete in Rails:

```
<%= text_field_tag('user', "", :placeholder => 'Enter a user...', class: "users",
                   data: {autocomplete_source: User.order(:lastname, :firstname).map { |u| {:label => getLabel(u.firstname, u.lastname).html_safe, :id => u.id} }}) %>
```

I am trying to display HTML in the labels, for instance bolding the text, and eventually to display perhaps an image in each row.

```
  def getLabel(firstname, lastname)
   "<b>" + firstname + " " + lastname + "</b>"
  end
```

This always renders as plain text in the results:

```
<b>John Smith</b>
```

What is the best way to get the labels to be rendered as HTML? Any help is appreciated.

### Edit:

```
  $('.users').autocomplete
    source: $('.users').data('autocomplete-source')
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $( ".users" ).val( ui.item.value );
      $( "#user_id" ).val( ui.item.id );
      $( "#select_user" ).submit();
```

**HTML:**

```
<input class="users" data-autocomplete-source="[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;\u003Cb\u003EJohn Smith\u003C/b\u003E&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:4}]" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Enter a user..." type="text" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out with help from this example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

```
$(".users").autocomplete(
  dataType: "json"
  source: $('.users').data('autocomplete-source')
  minLength: 2
  select: (event, ui) ->
    $(".users").val(ui.item.value);
    $("#user_id").val(ui.item.id);
    $("#select_user").submit();
).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = (ul, item) ->
  $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete", item).append("<a>" + "<img src='" + item.img + "'>" + item.label + "</a>").appendTo( ul )
```

Added image to results set:

```
{:label => u.firstname + " " + u.lastname, :id => u.id, :img => u.avatar_url}
```

This allowed me to output the image, any other html could be manipulated in the js.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you declare your string as HTML-safe, it will always be escaped for you. This is a safety mechanism.

The most straight-forward method is to employ [`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) on the tags:

```
def get_label(firstname, lastname)
  [ '<b>', h([ firstname, lastname ].join(' '))), '</b>' ].join('').html_safe
end
```

Even better, you can use the helper methods to construct tags for you:

```
def get_label(firstname, lastname)
  content_tag('b', [ firstname, lastname ].join(' ')).html_safe
end
```

The second approach is better since you're not running the risk of accidentally declaring the name `html_safe`.

Comment: Hmmm. Both of these solutions still render plain text for me.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to try a different approach.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. It's almost as if it is being forced as plain text because it is in the 'data-autocomplete-source' attribute on the input field. I have updated my question on how it renders. Should this be converted back into html on the js end? Quite at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change the css for autocomplete to display the input anyway you'd like.

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
  font-weight:bold;
  /* other changes ... */
}
```

This way you don't have to add any extra html to your input strings.